# How can i implement the erase method?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

```
void reserve( int newCapacity ){
     Object *oldArray = objects;
     int numToCopy = newCapacity < theSize ? newCapacity : theSize;
     newCapacity += SPARE_CAPACITY;
     objects = new Object[newCapacity];
     for( int k=0; k < numToCopy; k++ )
         objects[k] = oldArray[k];
     theSize = numToCopy;
     theCapacity = newCapacity;
     delete [ ] oldArray;
}
```

How can i implement the erase method, probably using reserve()?

```
iterator erase ( iterator position ){
    if (position + 1 != end())
       copy(position + 1, finish, position);
    --finish;
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered looking through existing open-source implementations?

Comment: well i looked stl source but it was complex.

Comment: Soemthing wrong with `std::vector`?

Comment: Then the fun should be finding the answer, not asking for it ;)

Comment: Well, Ive already finished implementing my own vector class. It was fun:)

Comment: sometimes i so wish i could downvote comments and hit people's rep. people seem to take advantage of this missing feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this ought to do it:

```
iterator erase ( iterator position ) {
  copy(position+1, end(), position);
  resize(size()-1);
  return position;
}
iterator erase ( iterator first, iterator last ) {
  copy(last, end(), first);
  resize(size()-(last-first);
  return first;
}
```